# C#_LINQ. Search in database just look like what i search

Tags: c#, database, linq

I want search `Personnel` according to `Personnel` code from database and insert `Personnel` Name into Label, now, i have a problem

for example:
when i do insert `Personal` with this code `11112222` And whenever I search the code that contains the numbers
("1" or "11" or "111" or "22" and ...etc) The personnel Shows, but i don't want it, i want to show me exactly look like code that i searched

```
private void btn_check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string z1 = txt_CodePersonnelZ1.Text;
    var query = db.tbl_PrsAdds.Where(c => c.Personely.Contains(z1)).Single();
    lbl_name.Text = query.Name;
}
```

Tanks for your help.

Comment: Once you get the data from the database and insert it into table db.tbl.PrsAdds you can extract the data from the table.

Comment: Then use `c.Personely.Equals(z1)` instead of `Contains(z1)`?

Comment: tanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

From your requirements it seems that you don't need `Contains` but you need to search for a specific term. If that's true, then you could try something like the below snippet:

```
private void btn_check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string z1 = txt_CodePersonnelZ1.Text;
    var prsAdd = db.tbl_PrsAdds.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Personely == z1);
    lbl_name.Text = prsAdd != null ? prsAdd.Name : string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem

```
private void btn_check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string z1 = txt_CodePersonnelZ1.Text;
    var query = db.tbl_PrsAdds.Where(c => c.Personely.Length == z1.Length && c.Personely.Contains(z1)).Single();
    lbl_name.Text = query.Name;
}
```